# Cannot parse SQL Server XML column when reportdefinition is "defaultfontfamily"

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using an XML column in a SQL Server table. There are certain rows where the XML is not properly parsed, and I have identified why - for rows where it cannot be read, the XML is using 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily'. I have tried adding it as a namespace, but it did not help.

Those rows with no problem have xml namespaces as:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
```

...

Those rows with a problem have xml namespaces as:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily" MustUnderstand="df">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
```

...

You can see when it works when xmlcolumn.values are assigned - these do not contain the additional line <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
[image: The SQL - no values assigned to xmlcolumn.value]

Here is the SQL I am using.  Thank you in advance.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
( DEFAULT 
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'
, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS ReportDefinition
, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily' AS df)
SELECT  
CATDATA.Name AS ReportName
,CATDATA.Path AS ReportPathLocation
,xmlcolumn.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS DataSetName  
,xmlcolumn.value('(Query/DataSourceName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)') AS DataSourceName 
,xmlcolumn.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(2500)') AS CommandText
,reportXML
FROM (  
    SELECT C.Name
    ,c.Path
    ,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),C.Content)) AS reportXML
    FROM  ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
    WHERE  C.Content is not null
    AND  C.Type = 2
    ) CATDATA 
outer APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') xmltable ( xmlcolumn )
--WHERE xmlcolumn.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)') LIKE '%2_%'
ORDER BY CATDATA.Name
```

Comment: Please show a full sample XML which doesn't work. Your existing sample doesn't show the problem, as the node `Query` and `DataSourceName` etc are not present, and it seems you are missing other levels of nodes.

Comment: I don't think the problem you've identified is the problem. XML namespaces matter. The problem is that the reports are targeting different versions of SQL Server Reporting Services and so their namespaces (including the default namespace) are different than what you're querying. The default namespace you're referencing, `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition` is for SSRS 2012, whereas the document sample you've included has a default namespace for a different version of SSRS, `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition`.

Answer (score 3):

Your exact XML is unclear as you haven't shown us a full sample, so I've had to guess. It seems `Report` has a different default namespace.

You have three options:

- Either ignore the namespace completely using `*:`

  ```sql
  WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
  ( DEFAULT 
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'
  , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS ReportDefinition
  , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily' AS df
  )
  SELECT  
    C.Name AS ReportName
  ,C.Path AS ReportPathLocation
  ,xmlcolumn.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS DataSetName  
  ,xmlcolumn.value('(*:Query/*:DataSourceName/text())[1]','VARCHAR(250)') AS DataSourceName 
  ,xmlcolumn.value('(*:Query/*:CommandText/text())[1]','VARCHAR(2500)') AS CommandText
  ,reportXML
  FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
  CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
        CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), C.Content)) AS reportXML
  ) CATDATA 
  OUTER APPLY reportXML.nodes('/*:Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet') xmltable ( xmlcolumn )
  WHERE C.Content is not null
    AND C.Type = 2
  ORDER BY C.Name
  ```
- Or you can use multiple `.nodes`

  ```sql
  WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
  ( DEFAULT 
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'
  , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' AS r2016
  , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS ReportDefinition
  , 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily' AS df)
  SELECT  
    C.Name AS ReportName
  ,C.Path AS ReportPathLocation
  ,ISNULL(
      xmlcolumn1.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)'),
      xmlcolumn2.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)')) AS DataSetName  
  ,ISNULL(
      xmlcolumn1.value('(Query/DataSourceName/text())[1]','VARCHAR(250)'),
      xmlcolumn2.value('(r2016:Query/r2016:DataSourceName/text())[1]','VARCHAR(250)')) AS DataSourceName 
  ,ISNULL(
      xmlcolumn1.value('(Query/CommandText/text())[1]','VARCHAR(2500)'),
      xmlcolumn2.value('(r2016:Query/r2016:CommandText/text())[1]','VARCHAR(2500)')) AS CommandText
  ,reportXML
  FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
  CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
        CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), C.Content)) AS reportXML
  ) CATDATA 
  OUTER APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') xmltable1 ( xmlcolumn1 )
  OUTER APPLY reportXML.nodes('/r2016:Report/r2016:DataSets/r2016:DataSet') xmltable2 ( xmlcolumn2 )
  WHERE C.Content is not null
    AND C.Type = 2
  ORDER BY C.Name
  ```

It's hard to say which version is faster. Ignoring namespaces is slow, but so is querying twice.

Note other improvements:

- Use of `CROSS APPLY` for the conversion to avoid nesting.
- Use of `/text()` to increase performance when doing XQuery.
- If you can change your column to actually be `xml` and avoid the conversion that would be good.

---

As a side note, if you actually wanted that `WHERE`, the best way to do it would be to put it inside the `.nodes` (note the use of `CROSS APPLY` here, not `OUTER APPLY`.

```sql
CROSS APPLY reportXML.nodes('
  /*Report/*:DataSets/*:DataSet
  [*:Query/*:CommandText/text()[contains(., "2_")]
  ') xmltable ( xmlcolumn )
```

Comment: It's comes down to personal preference but I'd prefer to use alternative paths in XPath Sequences over using namespace wildcards - less surprises when new namespaces appear on the scene. Or, put another way, if you're going to use wildcard namespaces in your paths you might as well not declare xmlnamespaces at all.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't disagree with your sentiment, but often you have to deal with other people's XML, and usually the only surprise is a random change to the namespace and not to any of the node names. Namespaces were invented so that you could combine XML documents without name clashes, but noone ever does that.

Comment: I've also modified teh answer to match with your guesses on the namespaces

Comment: Thank you both.  I ended up using the option to ignore the namespace completely and using wildcards, since after adding r2016 it revealed that there were even more namespaces to worry about (like 2008 report definitions).  Ignoring namespaces, though slower as mentioned, is more thorough.  Thank you, I learned from this.